# extract multiple patterns from string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a string:

```
a <- ":amount_min: !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.8e2 :operator_min: gt :amount_max: !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.1e4 :operator_max: lt"
```

I would like to restore it as:

```
a <- "min: 80, max:1000"
```

where: `0.8e2 = 80` and `0.1e4 = 1000`.

How can I do this using regular expression?

Comment: Can you please explain, where and what the strings are, that you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

One solution, which uses the colon in front of the numbers:

```
a <- ":amount_min: !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.8e2 :operator_min: gt :amount_max: !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.1e4 :operator_max: lt"

find_pos   <- gregexpr(pattern = ":[[:digit:]]", text = a)
get_string <- gsub(pattern = ":", "", substring(a,first=find_pos[[1]],last=find_pos[[1]]+5))
final      <- paste("min: ", as.numeric(get_string[1]), ", max: ", as.numeric(get_string[2]))
```

I also have a hardcoded soluation:

```
first_split <- strsplit(a, "BigDecimal 18:" )

min_val <- strsplit(first_split[[1]][2], ":")[[1]][1]
max_val <- strsplit(first_split[[1]][3], ":")[[1]][1]

final <- paste("min: ", as.numeric(min_val), ", max: ", as.numeric(max_val))
```

There are other solutions to extract the 0.8e2, but this value can always be translated by `as.numeric`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt using simple regex along with `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package,

```
library(stringr)

paste(str_extract_all(a, 'amount_min|amount_max', simplify = TRUE), 
      as.numeric(str_extract_all(a, '[0-9]\\.[0-9]e[0-9]', simplify = TRUE)), 
      sep = ':', collapse = ', ')

#[1] "amount_min:80, amount_max:1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `regmatches` + `gsub`

```
res <- toString(gsub("amount_",
                     "",
                     paste(unlist(regmatches(a,gregexpr("amount_min:|amount_max:",a))),
                           as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(a,gregexpr("\\d+?\\.?\\d+e[+-]?\\d+",a)))))
                     )
                )
```

such that

```
> res
[1] "min: 80, max: 1000"
```